# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll' while scrapimg from wikipedia

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, attributeerror

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
for link in bsobj.find("div",{"id":"bodycontent"}).findAll("a", href = 
re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$")):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

When i run this code i am getting an error.
This is the error I am getting;

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/shubham/PycharmProjects/testday1/scrapping/lamdaexp.py", line 9, in 
>       for link in bsobj.find("div",{"id":"bodycontent"}).findAll("a", href = re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$")):
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Please help me with this. This is in a youtube video tutorial and it is running fine in the tutorial video while, in my PyCharm it is showing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ID is `bodyContent` and not `bodycontent`.
C! not c.